# При проверке на содержание слова стиль меню меняется везде

Tags: javascript, jquery, условия

Имеется проверка в меню

```
if ($('#header .lab-menu-horizontal ul li.level-1 ul li:last-child >a').text().indexOf('All subcategory')!= -1) {
  $('#header .lab-menu-horizontal ul li.level-1 ul li:last-child >a').addClass("vse_cat")
}
```

проблема - меняются все элементы с `li:last-child >a`

Пробовал добавлять `$(this)` - результата не получил (возможно синтаксис не тот)

Как получить смену стиля в нужном месте при условии?

структура меню после работы скрипта имеет вид

```
<div class="lab-menu-col col-xs-12 col-sm-2   ">                                                        <ul class="ul-column ">
.....
<li class="menu-item  item-line  ">
<a href="#" class="vse_cat">All subcategory</a>
</li>
</ul>
                                                                                                </div>
<div class="lab-menu-col col-xs-12 col-sm-4   ">
<ul class="ul-column ">                                                                                                 
    .....
<li class="menu-item  item-header  ">
<a href="#" class="vse_cat">Příslušenství</a>                                                                               </li>                                                                                                       </ul>                                                                                       </div>
```

где .... - n элементов

то-есть идет добавление class="vse_cat" к каждому последниму элементу меню

Comment: Покажите структуру вашего меню. Сколько там пунктов, вложенность и всё прочее. Покажите код, и объясните, при каком условии вы собираетесь менять стиль меню.

Comment: Тут нужно добавить (как минимум) критерии "нужности" места, и пояснить термин "место" в контексте задачи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[.each() | jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

```js
/* Проходимся по всем найденым */
$('li:last-child >a').each(function() {
  /* Проверяем подходит ли нам данный элемент */
  if ($(this).text().indexOf('All subcategory') != -1) {
    /* Добавляем класс, если подходит */
    $(this).addClass("vse_cat");
  }
});
```

```css
.vse_cat {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#">subcategory</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">subcategory</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">All subcategory</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">All subcategory</a></li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Příslušenství</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Příslušenství</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Příslušenství</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Příslušenství</a></li>
</ul>
```